# Integrate Spring Social with Play

Tags: playframework, spring-social

Anyone know whether it's possible to integrate Spring Social with Play framework. I'm facing some issues with integration as Spring Social is using Servlet API.

Answer (score 3):

The quick answer is yes, it should be possible to integrate Spring Social with Play. The more accurate answer, however, is that Spring Social was not developed with Play in mind. While it is possible, there is nothing existing that will do that for you.

Once you have an access token, you should be able to use Spring Social's API bindings as well as the persistence pieces of the connection framework separate from the Servlet API. But certainly, ConnectController is servlet-based. I suppose you could still use this alongside Play, essentially redirecting out of your app to ConnectController to do the connection work and then back to Play for everything else, but that could be awkward.

The bulk of what ConnectController does is captured in the ConnectSupport class. This class is not entirely servlet API-free, but it is close to being servlet API-free. At very least, you could draw inspiration from it and create something that works well with Play.

If you decide to take on the challenge of creating integration between Play and Spring Social, *PLEASE* let us know. We'd love to promote your extension to Spring Social. I imagine you're not the only one wondering if it can be done.